# How to return exception from common error handler in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, es6-promise, asynccallback

My API is in nodejs with a layered architecture. Im facing problem in returning an error from anywhere in the application. My express error handler is capturing the error but then my controller logic is also getting executed. Below is my sample code.

```
//accountcontroller.ts

updateAccountStatus = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: any): Promise<any> => {
    let responseFromService = await AccountService.updateAccountStatus(
        parseInt(req.params.accountId),
        next
    );

    // even after the exception it comes here, after visiting the express default error code
    if (responseFromService !== undefined) {
        responseHandler(res, 200, responseFromService);
    }

    if (responseFromService.err) {
       return next(responseFromService);
    }


//accountService.ts

  public updateAccountStatus = async (accountId: number, next: any): Promise<any> => {
    let accountStatusReponse = await accountRepository.updateAccountStatus(accountId, next);

    return accountStatusReponse;
  };

//accountRepository.ts

public updateAccountStatus = async (accountId: any, next: any): Promise<any> => {
        try {

        const updateAccountStatus = await Accounts.updateOne(
          { id: accountId },
          { accountStatus: true }
        );
        if (updateAccountStatus) {
          return updateAccountStatus;
        } else {
          throw new Error("Error while saving the data");
        }

    } catch (error) {
      error.err = error.message;
      error.status = 500;
      return next(error);
    }
  };
```

//responseHandler is my commons file to return the responses.

```
responseHandler.ts

class responseHandler {
  constructor() {}
  statusCodeResponse = (
    response: any,
    message: string,
    statusCode: number,
  ): void => {
    response.statusMessage = statusMessage;
    response
      .status(statusCode)
      .json(
        response: response,
        message: message
        )
      );
  };
}
```

//app.js

```
import accountRouter from "./routes/accountroute";

var app = express();
app.use("/accounts", accountRouter);
```

Any suggestions on how do I make returns so that in case of an exception the control don't move back to the previous file.

Comment: @jfriend00 - in the app.js i register my routes 

import accountRouter from "./routes/accountroute";

accountRoute.ts

accountsRouter.put("/:accountId/updateAccountstatus", accountController.updateAccountstatus);

Comment: @jfriend00 - i have how the routes are registered in app.js